# Neo4j Cypher : return nodes with id as a dictionary

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with these properties:

```
MATCH (n:A) RETURN n
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "114s09A.1",
    "_id": "114s09A.1",
    "id": "114s09A.1",
    "created_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.256000000Z",
    "type": "A",
    "updated_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.256000000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "114s09A.2",
    "_id": "114s09A.2",
    "id": "114s09A.2",
    "created_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.257000000Z",
    "type": "A",
    "updated_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.257000000Z"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to build the cypher query so that the result would be shaped as a dictionary where `id` would be the key ?

```json
[
  {
    "114s09A.1": {
      "name": "114s09A.1",
      "id": "114s09A.1",
      "created_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.256000000Z",
      "type": "A",
      "updated_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.256000000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "114s09A.2": {
      "name": "114s09A.2",
      "id": "114s09A.2",
      "created_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.257000000Z",
      "type": "A",
      "updated_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.257000000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

The closest I came up to so far is :

```
MATCH (n:A) RETURN n._id AS _id, properties(n) AS properties
```

```json
[
  {
    "_id":"114s09A.1",
    "properties":{
      "name": "114s09A.1",
      "id": "114s09A.1",
      "created_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.256000000Z",
      "type": "A",
      "updated_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.256000000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id":"114s09A.2",
    "properties":{
      "name": "114s09A.2",
      "id": "114s09A.2",
      "created_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.257000000Z",
      "type": "A",
      "updated_n4j": "2020-12-21T09:56:11.257000000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with the default Cypher syntax, however if you have the apoc library installed, you can do this :

```
MATCH (n:A)
RETURN apoc.map.setKey({}, n.id, n{.*})
```